# Where can I find data on daily option volume by the premium paid?

Tags: options

I am searching for a site that offers details on sales of options on a daily basis.  For example, AAPL $305 MAY 1st CALLS show a high/low of $0.83/$0.01 on May 1st.  I would like to know how many contracts sold at each premium during the day.

I am always curious how, for some options, the high/low spread is so wide and the high is usually unbelievably high.  I always wonder how a sale could go through at such a high price and how many contracts sold at that price and when. It often doesn't make sense.

If anyone knows any site that offers detailed daily option transaction data (ideally for free), please let me know.  Also, if anyone knows how these option sales sometimes go through at what appears to be a ridiculously high price, I would really appreciate your insights.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**OPRA Data**

Last Sale information for all US options exchanges is generally distributed in "real-time" through the OPRA market data feed, and many brokers offer historical versions of that data through their market data services.  For this specific example however, my broker does not offer time and sales for expired options.

The OPRA time and sales data should include flags/codes to indicate whether or not the trade was the result of a complex order etc.

The data unfortunately is not free (the exchanges receive a significant portion of their revenue from subscribers and distributors of OPRA data).  Some brokers will eat that cost if you have an account with them to trade options, and some brokers will grant you access to historical OPRA time and sales data.

Vendors of OPRA data can be found on their home page under 'Find a vendor'.
https://www.opraplan.com

**Why could the price be so high?**

*Underlying Price Movements*

The price of options change as the price of the underlying security changes.   On that day AAPL traded from 285.85 to 299.00 and in particular, moved by about $10 during the first 30 minutes of trading.  With such a large movement early on, it would seem at the time that the probability that the 305 call option would expire in-the-money would seem more likely and could explain the high price.

*Market Maker Quote Width*

Market makers may also widen their quotes when they are uncertain about market conditions.   Typically they are limited to quoting $5.00 wide unless it is a high priced or extremely volatile security.

*Market Orders*

Some market participants (or their brokers) may send market orders, so would be willing to trade at the prevailing bid at the displayed price rather than patiently placing a limit order and waiting.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the volume and price of option trades in Time & Sales in/at a decent broker's platform/web site.  You're going to need some clever way to data scrape if you want to collect the data because it could be 100's of pages daily for an underlying with liquid options, even 1000's for something like the SPY.  You're not going to find a free web site that offers this because this is data storage  intense.

The bid/ask spread is often wide because there are no participants other than the market maker.  That can distort the appearance of option fair value versus underlying price.  For example, a 50 delta option has  a quote of $4.50 x $5.20 with an underlying that trades in a narrow range. A trade at the bid and then a trade at the ask implies a $1.40 move in the underlying when in fact, no such thing happened. However, I suspect that you are asking about the above pricing except that a trade goes off at $6.00 which is far from reality.  The answer is combo orders.  Here's why...

Suppose I own an $50 put quoted at $4.00 x $4.20 and I want to roll it down to the $48 put which is $2.80 x $3.00.  I place a combo (spread) order splitting the B/A for a credit of $1.20.  I don't care what the fill is on the individual legs because whatever they are, I get a $1.20 credit per spread.  Occasionally, the individual legs are filled way outside normal pricing.  On one spread, I might get a credit of $5.00 and on the other, a debit of $3.80, still netting me my $1.20.  Why does this happen?  One of these legs might be mispriced.  More likely, there's a 3rd party buying or selling calls (perhaps mispriced) and the MM is linking that trade with one of mine via a conversion or reversal.  And if no mispricings, the MM is simply capturing multiple spreads while laying off the risk via the arbs.

Comment: Thanks Bob.  In the case of my AAPL $305 CALL example expiring on the same day, the bid/ask spread was pretty normal and close together, it was the high fill of the day that was way out of whack.  I suspect it was due to the combo order scenario you described rather than a lucky (or unlucky if you were on the wrong side of the trade) market fill.  Thanks again for the great insight.

Comment: Regarding combos: they should show up in the time/sales data in the flags. Usually the exchanges or your broker use the prevailing (N)BBO of the various legs to synthesize the price of the combo.  Many combos are synthesized from the exchange's own order book, for example the price of the combo will be calculated from the price of the legs, and if you post a complex order, the exchange will post a synthetic leg in the regular order book (so if someone trades it, they will execute your combo).  Market makers are generally not directly involved unless your broker is doing PFOF.

Comment: Thank you for the insightful responses. They have been very helpful.